# Issue in SVM response opencv

Tags: java, opencv3.0, sift, surf

I am working on *breast cancer detection system* and using miniMias dataset. I am on final step, I am extracting **SIFT,SURF** features from *ROI* and for different **ROI** I have different number of features so I got different number of *descriptors*.
What I am doing?

1. Finding least number of **SIFT,SURF** *descriptors* of all dataset (so that training data size will be same).
2. Inserting both **SIFT,SURF** *descriptors* (starting index to min length) in single vector (first sift then surf).

So that's how I am passing features to **SVM** but I am not getting desired response on testing data, accuracy is less than 50% on testing data. I have also tried shuffling but same result. Is there any problem with features? Can  someone tell what should I do ?

This is how I set SVM parameters .

```
CvSVMParams params=new CvSVMParams();
params.set_svm_type(CvSVM.C_SVC);
params.set_kernel_type(CvSVM.LINEAR);
TermCriteria termC = new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6);
params.set_term_crit(termC);
CvSVM classifier = new CvSVM();
classifier.train(feature, label, new Mat(), new Mat(), params);
```

Answer (score 1):

In SVM there many parameters that helps us get accurate results. Some of the are:-

1) Choosing the right type of Kernel for our training data you are using Linear kernel trying using another types of kernels such as RBF and see the accuracy then choose the kernel type with highest accuracy. By the way RBF is mostly used kernel types and better performs for non-linear separable datasets.

2) Choosing the optimal parameters C and gamma. You have to choose optimal values for the C and gamma parameters in opencv SVM or you can also use SVM's train_auto method in stead of train then this method will choose automatically an optimal values for C, gamma and other parameters.

Use a code similar to this it is C++ but is very easy to change it to java

```
cv::SVMParams params;
        params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF; //CvSVM::RBF, CvSVM::LINEAR ...
        params.svm_type=SVM::C_SVC;
        params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,100000,0.000001);

SVM svm;    svm.train_auto(samples,labels,Mat(),Mat(),params,2,SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::C),SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::GAMMA),SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::P),SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::NU),
                     SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::COEF),SVM::get_default_grid(SVM::DEGREE),false);

    char *fs="svmFile.yml";
    svm.save(fs);
```

Comment: try using SVM.get_default_grid(CvSVM.GAMMA) use this link http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/org/opencv/ml/CvSVM.html#train_auto(org.opencv.core.Mat

Comment: I have done it manually (created own class with these methods) but same accuracy

Comment: If you don't use the train_auto method please search for "how to get optimized values of C and GAMMA in SVM" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757495/selecting-c-and-gamma-value